# Unity 3d Cardboard Demo Scene No Sound

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am trying to test the google cardboard unity 3d ios demo. To test if it supports spatial audio. If i hit the play button on my editor, no sound comes out. I have went through the documentation and can't seem to find anywhere where it says audio does not work in play mode.

I also tried to toggle the audio button on the toolbar but still not getting any sound.

Unfortunately I do not have a device to test and had to try the demo on an simulator  and still got no sound at all.

If you cannot assist with getting audio of the cube working in playmode, i would be glad if  someone could tell me if the CubeSound.wav is played as spatial audio on an actual device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your Cardboard test with a real device. This will make it easier to determine the problem. Cardboard is not expensive. Just throw any Android/Iphone device inside it and continue your programming. If you don't have any mobile device, you can borrow from your friends/families for testing.

As for your question, the current version of Unity does **not** support spatial audio. You have to use plugin in other to use spatial audio. There was a new beta release yesterday (4/27) that supports Spatializer natively and that is **UNITY 5.4.0B16**. You can get it from [here](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta). Spatializer won't work on other version unless you use a plugin.

Comment: Thanks i totally missed this notice:
Note: For Unity 5.2+ users, CardboardAudio Spatializer must be selected as the Spatializer Plugin in the Edit > Project Settings > Audio : Spatializer Plugin dropdown menu. This step is not required for users with Unity 5.1 or earlier.

Comment: The latest beta supports it now. Glad you got it sorted out.